# Проблема с установкой Kali на ноут с AMD Ryzen 7 6800h

Tags: linux, debian, установка, kali-linux

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Нужна помощь без совета поставить другую ОС. Устанавливаю Kali на новый ноут Asus Rog Strix (AMD Ryzen 7 6800h, NVIDIA 3060), но после установки на отдельный от Windows 11 ssd(400 Gb) после перезагрузки и выбора в загрузчике(grub) ос кали появляется ошибка и дальше ничего не происходит. Образ (kali-linux-2022-W23-установщик-amd64.iso) брал в репозитории(bare metal). До этого пытался загружать рабочий стол Kali Live, но дальше этой ошибки загрузка с флешки не проходила. Пробовал установить также Ubuntu (в нем отдельно установщика для AMD не нашёл), но та же история. Однако если загрузить Ubuntu Live, то рабочий стол загружается и проходит дальше этой ошибки которую приложу ниже в фото. Так же в режиме загрузки с флешки работает Tails. Под словом работает (Ubuntu и Tails) я в первую очередь понимаю загрузку системы дальше черного экрана с ошибками. Специально отключал ssd с Windows, чтобы исключить влияние второй ОС на загрузку, и ставил Kali на один  единственный диск, но та же история :(. Пишет ошибки UEFI, но из-за них ли загрузка не проходит дальше или эти ошибки не влияют непонятно. Не знаю важно ли это, на на виртуалке все работает, правда не без тормозов. Прошу дать советы тем кто сталкивался и знает что сделать чтобы заработало[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ix9SN.jpg): https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHsOD.jpg

Comment: А зачем ваш кали линукс? Кали линукс проф. дистрибутив, там много проф. инструментов которые нужны только специалистам, а для обычного пользователя это просто нагрузка системы, вам бы я посоветовал устанавливать XUbunutu или Linux Mint, эти системы лучше подходят для новичков, для XUbuntu написано много дров и Ubuntu в принципе хорошо подходит для новичков в линукс, а в Linux Mint привычный интерфейс(Виндоусавидный) + большое комьюнити которое сможет помочь.

Comment: Я посмотрел ошибки, последняя не критична, насчёт первых четырёх поищите в интернете для начала, а если не найдёте тогда лучше публикуйте в сообществе [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)(Там сидят множество специалистов по линуксу и по юниксу в общем, *в  том сообществе писать на английском*). Я сам помочь не смогу, у меня таких ошибок не возникало, соответственно ответы на них я не искал.

Comment: Я нашел [похожую проблему](https://askubuntu.com/q/1367587), человек в комменте написал, что ему nomodeset помогло